# Android check permissions from service

Tags: android

I have gps service where's it getting device gps location. But I noticed that in Anroid 6 and higher it can't to get location because need to get permission. Also I noticed that in service has inhirited method such as checkSelfPermission(String permission), int checkPermission(String permission, int pid, int uid). How can I check permission from service?

Comment: Try my library: https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions